# Не работает onclick в Хроме и Яндекс браузере

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

При выборе в select одной из опции у input должен измениться стиль. Первоначально инпут скрыт(display: none)
После клика по option стиль меняется на  display: inline
Не работает следующий код в хроме и яндекс браузере, в мозиле и ИЕ всё нормально, в чём может быть причина?

html

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option onclick="click2();" value="variable1">Первая</option>
    <option onclick="click2();" value="variable2">Вторая</option>
    <option onclick="click2();" value="variable3">Третья</option>
    <option onclick="click2();" value="variable4">Четвёртая</option>
    <option onclick="click1();" value="variable5">Добавить свою</option>
</select><br>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function click1 () {
        document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'inline'; 
    }
    function click2 () {
        document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none'; 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Просмотрите консоль хрома, есть ли в нём ошибки. Посмотрите элемент - меняется ли у него стиль. Посмотрите значения под отладчиком document.getElementById('test'), в момент выполнения функции.

Comment: Выставьте border у всех елементов. Может у вас елементы перекрывают друг-друга. Разные браузеры могут по разному "перекрывание" делать. Попробуйте поднять zIndex елемента

Comment: @Trymount консоль пустая, как-будто всё выполняется. Стиль у элемента не менятся

Comment: @nick_n_a этот вариант отпадает. Ставил в функции alert b вызывал её, опять же в мозиле всё ок, а хроме не показывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте событие **change** для отслеживания изменения значения формы

```js
function change() {
  var num = this.value[this.value.length - 1];
  
  switch (+num) {
    case 5: 
      document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'inline'; 
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="change.call(this)" class="form-control">
  <option value="variable1">Первая</option>
  <option value="variable2">Вторая</option>
  <option value="variable3">Третья</option>
  <option value="variable4">Четвёртая</option>
  <option value="variable5">Добавить свою</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<div id="test">Тестовый блок</div>
```

Comment: В консольку выводит, но стили всё равно не меняет.

Comment: @sbaikov Отредактировал код, добавил тестовый блок, можно использовать так

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось намного проще. значения в case нужно заносить в кавычки

Comment: @sbaikov не за что. Значит сделали не так как у меня в коде. В примере в switch перед переменной num стоит плюс, который переводит строку в число