# Не работает onclick на теге option в браузере Chrome

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, написанный на JavaScript, который в Firefox работает, а в Chrome нет.

В чем может быть причина?

```js
document.querySelector('option#sort-asc').onclick = function() {
  sortList('data-price');
}
document.querySelector('option#sort-desc').onclick = function() {
  sortListDesc('data-price');
}
document.querySelector('option#sort-rating').onclick = function() {
  sortListDesc('data-rating');
}

function sortList(sortType) {
  let items = document.querySelector('.goods-wrap');
  for (let i = 0; i < items.children.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j < items.children.length; j++) {
      if (+items.children[i].getAttribute(sortType) > +items.children[j].getAttribute(sortType)) {
        console.log(1);
        let replacedNode = items.replaceChild(items.children[j], items.children[i]);
        insertAfter(replacedNode, items.children[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function sortListDesc(sortType) {
  let items = document.querySelector('.goods-wrap');
  for (let i = 0; i < items.children.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j < items.children.length; j++) {
      if (+items.children[i].getAttribute(sortType) < +items.children[j].getAttribute(sortType)) {
        console.log(1);
        let replacedNode = items.replaceChild(items.children[j], items.children[i]);
        insertAfter(replacedNode, items.children[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}


function insertAfter(elem, refElem) {
  return refElem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, refElem.nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option id="sort-asc">Пункт 1</option>
  <option id="sort-desc">Пункт 2</option>
  <option id="sort-rating">Пункт 3</option>
</select>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr>
<div class="goods-wrap">

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="150" data-rating="3">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>Монітор 23.5" Samsung Curved</h1>
    <p>150 usd</p>
    <button class="buy">Купить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="110" data-rating="3">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>Монітор 24" Dell SE2416H Silver-Black</h1>
    <p>110 usd</p>
    <button class="buy">Купить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="310" data-rating="10">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>Монітор 27" MSI SE2416H Silver-Black</h1>
    <p>310 usd</p>
    <button class="buy">Купить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="168" data-rating="3">
    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>Монітор 23.8" LG 24MK600M</h1>
    <p>168 usd</p>
    <button class="buy">Купить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="138" data-rating="3">
    <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>Монітор 24" Samsung S24D300HS</h1>
    <p>138 usd</p>
    <button class="buy">Купить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="82" data-rating="9">
    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>Монітор 18.5" Acer V196HQLAb</h1>
    <p>82 usd</p>
    <button class="buy">Купить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="220" data-rating="8">
    <img src="images/7.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>Монітор 24" Asus VG248QZ </h1>
    <p>220 usd</p>
    <button class="buy">Купить</button>
  </div>


  <div class="goods-card" data-price="30" data-rating="3">
    <img src="images/10.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>Курс "Практический JavaScript"</h1>
    <p>30 usd</p>
    <button class="buy"><a href="">Купить</a></button>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, в firefox работает в хроме не работает, что еще нужно описать? '.goods-wrap' это блоки в которых фильтрует данные, обычный html код

Comment: Причина написана в js-консоли браузера

Comment: @andreymal, ничего там не написано, пустая строка

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, onclick не событие?

Comment: @РустамГимранов, принял правки как в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600207/256824, результат тот же

Comment: @РустамГимранов, как работать с этими тегами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не прослушивает браузер (Chrome) никакие события на теге `option` будь-то `click`, `fullscreen` или любое другое.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('#asc').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('Click asc');
  });
  document.querySelector('#desc').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('Click desc');
  });
  document.querySelector('#rating').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('Click rating');
  });

  document.querySelector('#sort_by').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('Click sort_by');
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="sort_by">
  <option id="asc">Пункт 1</option>
  <option id="desc">Пункт 2</option>
  <option id="rating">Пункт 3</option>
</select>
```

Используйте событие `change`, `input` на родительском элементе, например, `select`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('sort_by').addEventListener('input', sortBy);
});

function sortBy(event) {
  console.log('Input sort_by: ', this.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="sort_by">
  <option value="asc">Пункт 1</option>
  <option value="desc">Пункт 2</option>
  <option value="rating">Пункт 3</option>
</select>
```

В качестве родительского элемента также может выступать форма:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const MAIN_FORM = document.getElementById('main_form');

  MAIN_FORM && MAIN_FORM.addEventListener('input', formInputHandler);
});

function formInputHandler(event) {
  const parent = document.querySelector('.goods-wrap');

  const products = sortBy(
    parent.children,
    ...this.elements.sort_by.value.split('-')
  );

  products.map(function(product) {
    parent.appendChild(product)
  });
}

function sortBy([...collection], field, direction = 'asc') {
  collection.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.dataset[field] - b.dataset[field];
  });

  return 'asc' === direction ? collection : collection.reverse();
}
```

```css
.goods-card {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form id="main_form" class="" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sort_by">Сортировать</label>
    <select id="sort_by" name="sort_by">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Выберите ...</option>
      <option value="price-asc">Сначала дешевые</option>
      <option value="price-desc">Сначала дорогие</option>
      <option value="rating-desc">По рейтингу</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<hr>

<div class="goods-wrap">
  <div class="goods-card" data-price="150" data-rating="3">
    <h3>Монітор 23.5" Samsung Curved</h3>
    <p>150 usd</p>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="110" data-rating="3">
    <h3>Монітор 24" Dell SE2416H Silver-Black</h3>
    <p>110 usd</p>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="310" data-rating="10">
    <h3>Монітор 27" MSI SE2416H Silver-Black</h3>
    <p>310 usd</p>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="168" data-rating="3">
    <h3>Монітор 23.8" LG 24MK600M</h3>
    <p>168 usd</p>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="138" data-rating="3">
    <h3>Монітор 24" Samsung S24D300HS</h3>
    <p>138 usd</p>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="82" data-rating="9">
    <h3>Монітор 18.5" Acer V196HQLAb</h3>
    <p>82 usd</p>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="220" data-rating="8">
    <h3>Монітор 24" Asus VG248QZ </h3>
    <p>220 usd</p>
  </div>

  <div class="goods-card" data-price="30" data-rating="3">
    <h3>Курс "Практический JavaScript"</h3>
    <p>30 usd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600229/256824

Comment: не поверите, так тоже firefox работает, а хром нет, ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600229/256824 по этому примеру так же=)

Comment: Версия 79.0.3945.79 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит), оно показывает только sort_by, остальные нет

Comment: как к нему применить функции sortList(sortType) и sortListDesc(sortType)?

Comment: @аноним, добавлен пример реализации сортировки блоков.